# Windows 10 pro patches issue

Tags: windows-10

Please help for this

Windows 10 Cumulative Updates KB4013429, KB4013198, KB4012606 is showing the following error not applicable to this computer when trying to install in windows 10 pro. Please provide a solution

Comment: Did the updates download automatically? Or you try to install them manually?

Comment: Why do you believe you need to install KB4013429 and KB4012606 they go to entirely different branches of Windows 10 and are not applicable to your current installation

Answer (score 2):

> Windows 10 Cumulative Updates KB4013429, KB4013198, KB4012606 is showing the following error not applicable to this computer when trying to install in windows 10 pro.

- KB4013429 is for 1607 which isn't applicable to your system because it's very likely you have 1703 currently installed.
- KB4013198 is the 1703 March cumulative security quality rollup patch but the April patch would have supersede it.
- KB4012606 goes to 10240 which also isn't t applicable to your installation.

> Please provide a solution

Stop trying to install patches that are not applicable to your system.